# Data Provider relation not getting required data

Tags: php, yii

Guardian model:(relation)

```
'studentsGuardians' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'StudentsGuardian', 'guardian_id'),
```

Student model relation:

```
'studentsGuardians' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'StudentsGuardian', 'student_id'),
```

Students Guardian model relation:

```
'guardian' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Guardian', 'guardian_id'),
                        'student' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'student_id'),
```

Now in controller i want to select those students whose guardian_id=id but my code select all records without filtering. my code is

```
public function actionAssignGuardian($id)
        {

            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Student',
                                array(
                                    'criteria' => array(
                                        'with'=>array('studentsGuardians',
                                            array('criteria'=>
                                            array('with'=>array('guardian','condition'=>' guardian_id=:id',
                                                'params'=>array('id'=>$id))))),

                                    ),

                                    ));



            $this->renderPartial('Pages/_assignGuardian', array(
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'id'=>$id,
                    ));
        }
```

Kindly point me to correct way that how could i select those students whose guardian_id= given id in function. I am new to yii.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into `Student` model (below previous relation line `studentsGuardians`)

```
'guardians' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Guardian', array('guardian_id'=>'guardian_id'),'through'=>'studentsGuardians'),
```

Then you can do query like this

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Student',
            array(
                'criteria' => array(
                    'with'=>array(
                        'guardians' =>array(
                            'condition'=>' guardian_id=:id',
                            'params'=>array('id'=>$id)
                        )))    
            ));
```

(You should also dump `$id` to make sure that it is valid value)

Comment: In your defined relation have you written the relation name "guardian"? with "through" statement.

Comment: My typo, it should be 'studentsGuardians' (like the relation name that you got between `Student` and `Students Guardian` model)